# Ruby how to replace characters in a string with custom order?

Tags: ruby, string, sorting

i have a sring like this:

INPUT-String: euametH

and like to reorder the characters with this key: 7526134
That means the first char comes to the 7. position, the second char to the 5. position and so on, the third char to the 2. position and so on.

OUTPUT-String: Heuteam

How can i do this in Ruby ?

I have tried the following:  i have some enrypted messages. The first message is encrypted with a two-char key: like 21. This is easy to decrypt in ruby, i do this with this code:

```
File.read('/home/text').lines.each do |line|
  puts line.reverse
end
```

Fot the encrypted text with the 7-char key this is not possible.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @RELiABLE edit your question with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you are trying to do a simple cipher where the key corresponds to the order of the letters in the input message. So, split the key and the input message into single characters and rearrange:

```
>> input = "euametH"
=> "euametH"
>> keys = "7526134".chars.map(&:to_i)
=> [7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 3, 4]
>> output = keys.map{|k| input[k-1] }.join
=> "Heuteam"
>>
```

Comment: `input = "euametH".chars` can be skipped. The `[]` syntax works fine on a string, for instance:  `output = keys.map{|k| "euametH"[k-1] }.join`.

Comment: @Yule Thanks for your answer !  What means the k-1 in your code ?

Comment: @RELiABLE as arrays are 0 indexed, you need to take 1 away from the actual number to get the index. i.e. number 7, needs the 7th item in the array, so therefore the index is 6 (as arrays start from 0)